# How output is calculated?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
cout<<"dbba" - "bcx";
```

Here output is -5 in C++.

I want to know how this output is calculated here?

Comment: Difference of two pointer values maybe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behaviour of the code is undefined.

The string literals are of type `const char[5]` and `const char[4]` respectively. These *decay* to `const char*` pointers since they are the arguments of the binary operator `-`.

Computing the difference between two pointers is undefined unless they point to elements within the same array (or one beyond the last element of the array). In this context an object can be considered as a single-element array.

Comment: Behavior of the code is undefined means it will give output some random integer every time i run it ?

Comment: No it means it's undefined. The output is consistent with the two strings being contiguous in memory but **don't** ever rely on that.

Comment: @VishalGoel It might give you the same output all day one day, it might change for any reason at any time. It might not even give you a result if the compiler can detect it and optimize it out or it the program decides the crash. Undefined behavior can result in anything.

Comment: okay i understand .. actually it is the part of a small program i can post whole program if you want?

Comment: @VishalGoel: There's no need to do that; you have condensed the crux of the question well.

Comment: Hypertechnical note here: since the result is -5, the two arrays are clearly contiguous: `"bcx"` is immediately after `"dbba"`. That makes `"bcx"` a pointer to (gasp) one past the end of `"dbba"`, and the behavior is well defined. (Sorry, couldn't resist; nobody should read anything into this behavior, and certainly should not make any assumptions about the memory locations of string literals)

Comment: @PeteBecker:  What rule in the standard says that the literals need to be consecutive in memory?  I could write a compiler that places one literal in one Flash segment and the other in another flash segment?  Then again, one literal could be placed in the executable and the other in a constant data region (that is not in the executable).  All without violating the standard.

Comment: @PeteBecker - this is not defined behavior. What you mean is that you can imagine how the value -5 was obtained. A new version of the compiler could give an entirely different result, you could probably work out whats changed to cause the new result. But in both cases its still UB

Comment: @ThomasMatthews — perhaps you overlooked the part of my comment that says you “should not make any assumptions about the memory layout of string literals”.

Comment: Sheesh. No sense of humor.